# exception handling in C++: Throwing a double when using "throw(int)"

Tags: c++, int, double, try-catch

The following program always outputs "Error:double 10.2".

I do not understand why.
According to me, if fun1() allows only int to be thrown, the program should either
(1) crash
(2) or change the double to an int and then throw.
This means, the output should be "Error:int 10".
This is not the case, however. Can anyone explain ??

```
void fun1() throw (int)
{
    cout<<"3";
    throw 10.2;
    cout<<"4";
}

int main()
{
    try {   fun1(); }
    catch(int i) { cout<<"Error:int" <<i <<endl;}
    catch(double i) { cout << "Error:double" << i << endl; }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use the 'throw' function declaration, it's a crap feature and it has been deprecated.

Comment: Are you using MSVC? It never really supported exception specifications.

Comment: That should be `int main()`.

Comment: @Fanael: Yes, I am using MSVC.

Comment: Just tried out the program on g++. Worked as expected. Program terminates with the following message: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'double'
3Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your compiler isn't standard compliant. According to standard your program should end with calling [`std::unexpected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected) after letting `double` exception escape `fun1`.
That said - don't use exception specifications. They are deprecated and useless.

Comment: And here is an interesting read on the subject of why : http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Answer (score 3):

MSVC treats `throw(int)` as meaning simply "can throw anything", i.e. equivalent to `throw(...)`, see [Exception Specifications (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx)

This does not conform to the C++03 standard, but is actually more useful than the C++03 behaviour and is closer to the spirit of the C++11 standard.

In C++11 `throw(X)` is deprecated, the new form of exception specification is `noexcept` and can be `noexcept(true)` or `noexcept(false)`, equivalent to `throw()` and `throw(...)`, which is all that MSVC supports.

If you want to use the old-style exception specs, just use `throw()` to say "will not throw" and either nothing or `throw(...)` to say "might throw", and do not use `throw(X)`.  That will work consistently in C++03 and C++11 and across all compilers.

Comment: MSVC does not correctly support `throw()` either: ["However, if an exception is thrown out of a function marked throw(), the Visual C++ compiler will not call unexpected..."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx). You can't use any kind of `throw` specification portably between MSVC and a standard-compliant compiler.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that ... so it doesn't match the C++11 semantics, which state that `std::terminate()` is called if a `noexcept(true)` function (or `throw()`) throws